Why does the decryptRSA function return seemingly random output?
Inside of my RSA keygen and encryption/decryption program, the result of decryption is never the same output as the input. I am sure that the gcd(a,b) function and the carmichael(n) functions are working correctly, as is plainToNum(msg), so the issue must lie in either the rsaEncrypt(e,n,msg), the rsaDecrypt(d,n,msg), or the rsaKeygen() functions.
Source Code:
function rsaKeygen()
  p = math.random(50000,100000)
  while not isprime(p) do
    p = math.random(1,1000)
  end
  q = math.random(1,1000)
  while not isprime(q) do
    q = math.random(50000,100000)
  end
  local n = p*q
  totientN = carmichael(n)
  e = 2^16+1
  local d = 1%totientN/e
  p,q,totientN = nil,nil,nil
  return e,d,n
end

function encryptRSA(e,n,msg)
  local msg = plainToNum(msg)
  return msg^e%n
end

function decryptRSA(d,n,msg)
  local dec = msg^d%n
  return dec
end

According to my code, the keys are generated fine (maybe), and the keys work for encryption (they return a reasonable-looking result) and my algorithms are based on the Wikipedia page for RSA (cryptosystem).
As a set of test data, the result of plainToNum for the string "testing" is 1.16e+20, the encrypted num is 4566895.0, and the decrypted string is 165.910

RSA relies on exact integer arithmetic. Lua's number type is double-precision floating-point, and isn't suitable for implementing RSA. You'll need to use some kind of bigint library for Lua, or switch to a language that makes it easier to do bigint arithmetic. (I think this was already mentioned in the answer to your earlier question.)

Specific problems: d = 1%totientN/e gives just 1/e, which isn't what you want: you want an integer that's the inverse of e modulo totientN. And in msg^e%n, you lose precision unless msg^e is smaller than 2^53. And given that your e is 2^16+1, pretty much any value of msg (other than 0 or 1) is going to cause msg^e to overflow.

bigint library, remember?
